# Php script to plain text headers

Tags: php

I would like to know what are the correct headers to use in a php script to print plan text.

I'm using the following code:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=");
```

It's not working and all my content is coming back with no line spacing. Im using the content for bbcode forum posting. Can any one help me with the right headers to use so my browsers can see the text with spaces and line breaks.

Comment: How are you viewing the request that a `text/plain` Content-type header isn't doing what you expect? Please note that _Content-type_ HTTP response headers only apply to how the window object of the browser renders the response. So if you're using something like AJAX to fetch the response and then injecting it into the DOM, which was loaded with an html content-type, this won't give you the desired effect.

Comment: well my script is grabbing content from a database and using a template i made to arrange the content.

Answer (score 2):

There are two important distinctions that we need to consider when referring to how a browser will render content from an HTTP response.

1. How the request is made
2. How the response is used

If a request is made by the browser where the user enters the address into their browser's address bar, or by clicking a link on the page, the HTTP response header `Content-type` is initially used to figure out how to render the HTTP response.

However, if you are making an AJAX request via javascript, the `Content-type` header only effects how that `XMLHttpRequest` object deals with the HTTP response. Taking that response and trying to inject it directly into the DOM, for example, will not give the desired effect.

If this is the case then you need to wrap the content in [`<pre>` HTML tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) for the browser to know to render it as plain text.

> The **HTML <pre> element** (*or HTML Preformatted Text*) represents preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in a non-proportional ("[monospace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Style/monospace)") font exactly as it is laid out in the file. Whitespace inside this element is displayed as typed.

You also appear to be missing the charset in your header. Make sure to either specify that or omit it entirely in your response header.

Either

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf8');
```

Or

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

Comment: Is that really relevant to your question?

Comment: if we can link up ill teamview you and show you exactly what im trying to do are you down for that ? @sherif

Comment: Thanks I tried both of those and they still did not work.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's going to be any more productive than just elaborating on your question here. Nothing about the problem statement you present is unique or even remotely complex. It's actually relatively straight forward enough that I've already deduced your potential problem areas. Feel free to ask what about the actual answer I'm giving you doesn't address your question.

Comment: Unfortunately, "___did not work___" is not a useful metric to understand your problem. It doesn't tell me what you expected to happen that did not happen or what did not happen that you expect to happen. It also doesn't tell me what you may have done that caused unexpected results. You might as well just tell me "_it did stuff when I expected it to do other stuff_". Both are equally informative statements.

Comment: Yes but im not very good with php or coding so I could show over teamview and visual learn that would make it better for me i don't know all the terms to use to express what im trying to do, but if you know how i can fix this problem im having please let me know Thanks @sherif